# Moving one DIV element inside another in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, angular6, angular7

I am working with **Jquery** code in  Angular where I want to move one DIV element inside another 
 Here is my code

.ts file

```
moveButton(elem) {
  alert('hello' + elem);
  if ( $(elem).parent().attr('id') === 'oneDiv' ) {
    alert('hello' + elem);
    $(elem).detach().appendTo('#anotherDiv');

  } else {

    $(elem).detach().appendTo('#oneDiv');
  }
}
```

.html file

```
<div id="oneDiv">   
  <button id="btnDefault" class='btn123' (click)='moveButton(this)' type='button'> Button 1  </button>
  <button id="btnPrimary" class='btn123' (click)='moveButton(this)' type='button' > Button 2 </button>
  <button id="btnDanger" class='btn123' (click)='moveButton(this)' type='button' > Button 3 </button>
</div> 
<div id="anotherDiv"> </div>
```

But My code is not working may be because  detach() , parent() , attr()
do not work .

Comment: Are you working with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in angular but your jquery code inside the function works fine for me .. your problem maybe in the relation between the function and `(click)='moveButton(this)'`

this is how it works with jquery *without a function*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click' , '.btn123' , function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    if ( $(elem).parent().attr('id') === 'oneDiv' ) {
      $(elem).detach().appendTo('#anotherDiv');
    } else {
      $(elem).detach().appendTo('#oneDiv');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#oneDiv{
  background : red;
}
#anotherDiv{
  background : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="oneDiv">   
  <button id="btnDefault" class='btn123' type='button'> Button 1  </button>
  <button id="btnPrimary" class='btn123' type='button' > Button 2 </button>
  <button id="btnDanger" class='btn123' type='button' > Button 3 </button>
</div> 
<div id="anotherDiv"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `detach()` and `appendTo()` on same level, only `appendTo()` function is enough to do this.

I know you wanted to do this in AngularJS, but you can do this totally in jQuery, check below code:

```js
function moveButton(elem) {

  if ( $(elem).parent().attr('id') == 'oneDiv' ) {
    $(elem).appendTo('#anotherDiv');
  } else {
    $(elem).appendTo('#oneDiv');
  }
}
```

```css
#oneDiv{
border:solid 2px blue;
padding:20px
}


#anotherDiv{
border:solid 2px orange;
padding:20px;
margin-top:10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="oneDiv">   
  <button id="btnDefault" class='btn123' onclick='moveButton(this)' type='button'> Button 1  </button>
  <button id="btnPrimary" class='btn123' onclick='moveButton(this)' type='button' > Button 2 </button>
  <button id="btnDanger" class='btn123' onclick='moveButton(this)' type='button' > Button 3 </button>
</div> 
<div id="anotherDiv"> </div>
```